# Python json.dumps output add index

Tags: python, json

I currently have a csv to json python2
Here is a snippet of the code

```
csvFile = 'data.csv'
jsonFile = 'data.json'
data = {}
fieldNames = ("ID","Type","sensor_type","op_status","temp","unit","status")
with open(csvFile) as csvf:
   csvReader = csv.DictReader(csvf, fieldNames)
   lines = 0
   for rows in csvReader:
       data[lines]=rows
       lines=lines+1
with open(jsonFile, 'w') as jsonf:
    #print(json.dump(data,jsonf))
    jsonf.write(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
```

and the input data

```
14,Temp 1,Temperature,Nominal,27.00,C,'OK'
15,Temp 2,Temperature,Nominal,40.00,C,'OK'
```

And this is the file generated, as you you would expect:

```
{
    "0": {
        "unit": "C",
        "status": "'OK'",
        "sensor_type": "Temperature",
        "temp": "27.00",
        "Type": "Temp 1",
        "ID": "14",
        "op_status": "Nominal"
    },
    "1": {
        "unit": "C",
        "status": "'OK'",
        "sensor_type": "Temperature",
        "temp": "40.00",
        "Type": "Temp 2",
        "ID": "15",
        "op_status": "Nominal"
    }
}
```

However what I want to do is more like

```
{
  "Readings": [
    {
      "unit": "C",
      "status": "'OK'",
      "sensor_type": "Temperature",
      "temp": "27.00",
      "Type": "Temp 1",
      "ID": "14",
      "op_status": "Nominal"
    },
    {
      "unit": "C",
      "status": "'OK'",
      "sensor_type": "Temperature",
      "temp": "40.00",
      "Type": "Temp 2",
      "ID": "15",
      "op_status": "Nominal"
    }
  ]
}
```

This data is being sent over MQTT to home-assistant and I cannot access the "0"'th element so I need to convert it to be able to decode it.

How can I achieve this using python?

Regards

Comment: `data = {'Readings': []}` .. `data['Readings'].append(rows)`…!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of generating the index, just append rows to data dict

```
csvFile = 'data.csv'
jsonFile = 'data.json'
data = {"Readings":[]}
fieldNames = ("ID","Type","sensor_type","op_status","temp","unit","status")
with open(csvFile) as csvf:
   csvReader = csv.DictReader(csvf, fieldNames)
   lines = 0
   for rows in csvReader:
       data["Readings"].append(rows)
with open(jsonFile, 'w') as jsonf:
    #print(json.dump(data,jsonf))
    jsonf.write(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
```